# Fourier series and $f(x)=\sum_{h=-\infty}^{+\infty} y(h) e^{-i h x}$.

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

After some calculation on real function $f(x)$, I obtain the following
$$f(x)=\sum_{h=-\infty}^{+\infty} y(h) e^{-i h x}, \ \ x\in\mathbb R $$
where $y(h)$ are equally spaced samples of a real function $y(x)$. How RHS of the previous equation is interpretable? Can it be viewed as a Fourier series?

Comment: That is indeed a Fourier series.  I hope your function $f$ is periodic with period $2 \pi$.

Comment: Yes, it is. Thank you.